# Div click event not working using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a calculator. I want to add a click event to some of the columns using jQuery. I have looked at the other threads but did not find a solution. Also, I am using Codepen.

```js
$(document).ready()
{
  $(".buttons-display").click(function() {
    console.log("You just clicked a button!"); //Not Working
  });
}
```

```css
.row {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contanier-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="display-one"></div>
    <div class="row" id="display-two"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons">C</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons">CE</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons buttons-display">(</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons buttons-display">)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I placed the code in your question in a runnable snippet. Hopefully you can now see the syntax issues with your code.

Comment: Just to point you where to look at the ready function is wrong `$(document).ready(function(){...`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It works for me without changing anything, make sure jquery is included in codepen by going in settings/javascript/add external Javascript/

Comment: I'd be interested in how it worked for you as it is with the syntax issues. Also 'it works' isn't an answer.

Comment: I didn't change anything in the syntax, just copied and pasted your code, and with jquery included I had the "You just clicked a button!" in the console (when clicking)

Comment: Again - how? If you run the snippet in the question you'll just get errors due to the missing `}` and `function` definition

Comment: Forgot to include jQuery. It works without function definition.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too :

```
$(document).on('click', '.buttons-display', function () {
    console.log("You just clicked a button!"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).ready(function(){` instead `$(document).ready() {`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".buttons-display").click(function() {
    console.log("You just clicked a button!"); //Not Working
  });
})
```

```css
.row {
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contanier-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="display-one"></div>
    <div class="row" id="display-two"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons">C</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons">CE</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons buttons-display">(</div>
      <div class="col-md-3 buttons buttons-display">)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, but just for future reference it's much better to just flag questions like this - where the problem is purely due to syntax errors or typos - to be closed.